# Where is this Batman meme picture from?

Tags: dc, batman, history-of, robin, meme

I've seen many memes employing this scene of Batman slapping Robin:

[image]

Where is this taken from?

Comment: Is there anyway I can improve my answer?

Answer (score 2):

It's from [1965′s World’s Finest #153](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/World's_Finest_Vol_1_153).

> The story is based around an alternate reality in which Batman believes that Superboy and Superman are responsible for the death of his father.

[image]

([Source](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/my-parents-are-dead-batman-slapping-robin))